# Can a Mac PPC laptop airport card die unexpectedly?

Tags: airport-extreme, powerpc

So we have this ancient Mac laptop -- an 800 MHz G4 PPC running 10.4.11 -- this piece of hardware is so old, we bought it well before Sarah Palin started her first half term. But it's been serving purpose as an IMDB reference while watching TV, as well as a Facebook time-waster.

This morning my wife turned it on, and it came up with some message about Air Port not working. She continued on (so would I), but there was no airport indicator in the menubar, and System Prefs/Network tells me Airport isn't installed.

The card -- an Aria extreme -- is seated, but the lights don't come on.

Does this mean the card is hosed?  I don't want to shell out over $70, particularly when it might not work.  I mean, this laptop is so old, when I first lugged it through airports the 
security guy never asked me to turn it on.

Yes, I'm wasting all your time.  Sorry about that.  If no one here can hook me up with a free card to try, this baby's off to the local free geek.  Did I mention that the screen
goes all fuzzy every five minutes or so, and you need to cycle the lid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any updates have been installed recently, try to remove them.

If there hasn't been. It most likely is dead. Electronics die all the time. If it is very old, you may want to consider using wired/power socket networking or finding an alternate part on eBay or similar.